# Price Set Total Amount not displaying

Tags: price-sets

I have a WP civicrm install.  I am using a price set on a membership contribution page, but the total amount is not displaying.

All works fine on test drive but on the live page no total amount is displayed at all, either initially or when any items from the price set are chosen.

It seems like the price total calculation is working as when contribution is confirmed the next pages shows the correct amounts.

Comment: Have you checked in your browser's developer tools to see if the total amount is rendering?  It's possible that it's on the page but hidden for some reason (e.g., CSS affecting its display).

Comment: also compare with the dev site perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by disabling Wordpress Autoptimize plugin